# How to use variable for xml attribute value in vb 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, xpath, xml-parsing

I wonted to know if i can use a variable in selecting node statement ex:

```
Pgs = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/* [@Id = 160578]")
```

I need to replace this 160578 number with a variable?

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: It's Vb 2015 community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive (and prone to injection) is string manipulation e.g. `xmlDoc.SelectNodes(String.Format("/*[@Id = {0}]", yourVariable))`. The right approach would be to use the second argument to SelectNodes and implement variable resolution in an implementation of `XsltContext` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext(v=vs.110).aspx. The project https://mvpxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/4894 has a class `DynamicContext` doing that, although that project is done in C# you could of course compile it with VS and integrate the API into your VB code:

```
Dim idVar As Double = 160578
Dim dynContext As New DynamicContext
dynContext.AddVariable("id", idVar)
Pgs = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/*[@Id = $id]", dynContext)
```